# Android studio not importing image files correctly

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm making an app, so I decided to add a like a dislike button so that the user can like / dislike a post. However, even though my dislike.png image for the dislike button is in the *drawable* folder, it still appears red and doesn't not get pushed through when I commit it to github.

[I'm not allowed to embed images so here's the link for it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AetXu.png)

What can I do about this? 
Thanks!

Comment: You need to manually add it to your Git. After that, it should turn green (add new file) and be committed as usual.

Comment: Hey :) If it's an image file, do you mind telling me how I may do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to generate your image for all screens with this 
[service](http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html)
After that copy "res" folder from archive to you app folder

Answer (score 0):

Simple 3 steps:

Right-click on the file you would like to add:

[image: Right-click the file]

Open the *Git->* sub-menu and click *Add*:

[image: The Git submenu]

The file will now appear with green text:

[image: Green text]